# Use exists? with dynamic term

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a POST definition:

```
def create
  if Movie.exists?(title: 'The Batman')
    # your truck exists in the database
    render json: { body: 'Movie already exists'}
  else
    # the truck doesn't exists
    @movie = Movie.create!(movie_params)
    json_response(@movie, :created)
  end

end
```

This definition checks if there is already a movie with the title The Batman, if so it returns the json message. If it doesn't it creates the movie.

When I run my application with this code I get this in my Rails log:

> Movie Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `movies` WHERE `movies`.`title` = 'The Batman' LIMIT 1

The problem is that I have hard coded 'The Batman'. How can I get it to work with the title of the movie that's being posted from the front-end?

I've also tried this:

```
if Movie.exists?(title: @movies.title)
```

> NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass):

And this:

```
if Movie.exists?(title: Movie.title)
```

> NoMethodError (undefined method `title' for #):

I've read the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) but they also use static data instead of dynamic data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh? Just fetch it from params

```
 Movie.exists?(title: movie_params[:title])
```

Comment: Looks good, but that way isn't shown in the API http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F so how should I have known to type it like that?

Comment: I've worked quite a bit with Rails 4 but never saw annotation like this.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma: it's not some special magic syntax, BTW. It's a super-regular ruby method call (two calls actually). The `movie_params` method, you have it in the same file. If you did read a rails book, you'd know what it's for.

Comment: Hm guess some syntaxes have faded from memory after a lot of Java development. Thanks for the help, I'll dive back into some basic Rails guides.